# How can we show that for $\epsilon>0$, $\mathbb{P}([-N,N)^c)<\epsilon$?

Tags: probability-theory

I have the following question: i have been reading the wonderful book "Probability Theory" by A.A. Borovkov and on page 35, the author, after defining the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ of some real line interval $[a_i,b_i)$ as the sum of the the distribution function evaluated at the interval's endpoints, that is, $\mathbb{P}(A)=\sum_{i=1}^n(F(b_i)-F(a_i))$ for $A=\cup_{i=1}^n[a_i,b_i)$, he then proceed to prove the continuity of $\mathbb{P}$. At some point he claims that for interval $C_N=[-N,N)$ and for any $\epsilon>0$, we can choose an $N$ such that $\mathbb{P}(C_N^c)<\epsilon$. I am not sure about how to explicitly show this. That is, if the real line $\mathbb{R}$ is the whole sample space, then

$\mathbb{P}(C_N^c)=\mathbb{P}((-\infty,-N)\cup[N,\infty))$

$=F(\infty)-F(N)+F(-N)-F(-\infty)$

$=1-F(N)+F(-N)$.

If we let $N\rightarrow\infty$, this probability approaches zero by the properties of the distribution function $F$. But then, how can I use the $\epsilon$ argument and the choice of $N$?

Many thanks in advance, Christos Mix.

Comment: This $\epsilon$-$N$ description is just what the limit statement you made actually means.

Comment: Oh, then there is no reason to explicitly pick some $N$ and some $\epsilon$. Thanks, i thought there was something more to it!